# request->filled method can not see parameter, which exists within request data

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

In web.php file I have route like this:

```
Route::get('/list/{list_id}/edit',  [ListingController::class, 'edit']);
```

Then in ListingController:

```
public function edit(Request $request) {
    var_dump($request->list_id);
    var_dump($request->filled('list_id'));
    exit;
}
```

If url is like: `domain.com/list/20/edit`

result is: `string(2) "20" bool(false)`

So `$request->list_id` exists but `$request->filled('list_id')` gives FALSE. What is reason for that?

(P.S.  If pass parameter as usual GET parameter like `?list_id=20` then filled() method   gives TRUE).

Comment: Technically `list_id` is a route parameter, so may work differently. it's already required, so you don't need to check if it's filled. You can add `$list_id` to your function parameters, and it will have a value.

Comment: Sure, if no $list_id param present, then there is error, what I don't get is  if $request contains some data, (in this case which is route parameter), then why its metod `filled()` can not see same data?

Answer (score 2):

If you use it as a parameter in your route like `domain.com/list/20/edit` you need to specify it in your method:

```php
public function edit(Request $request, int $list_id) {
    var_dump($list_id);
    exit;
}
```

You can also omit the `Request` here as it is no longer used:

```php
public function edit(int $list_id) {
    var_dump($list_id);
    exit;
}
```

[See this example in the laravel documentation on basic controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `filled()` method is specifically designed to check if a value is present in the request's input data, which includes query parameters, form data, and JSON data, but not route parameters.

Instead you should try using the `has()` method like:

```php
$request->has('list_id')
```

Comment: Thanks, may be both functions filled() and has() also parsing query string and looking parameters there? because `$request->has('list_id')` also gives `false`

Comment: Oh. Try `$request->exists('list_id')` and let me know if that works.

Comment: `$request->exists('list_id')` also is `false`

Comment: how about `isset($list_id)`?